# How when clicking on the button I have the color of another element

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change the color of each input when clicking on the "check" button, I think I can do it using JavaScript.

I have tried different ways, but everything leads to the fact that they show how to change the color of the button when clicking on it, and I need to associate 5 elements with the button, most likely I need to use the ID (probably), but how?

```css
.letter {
  background-color: #e79e30;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  border-radius: 43px;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <button class="button-check">Проверить</button>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <input type="text" class="letter" />
  <input type="text" class="letter" />
  <input type="text" class="letter" />
  <input type="text" class="letter" />
  <input type="text" class="letter" />
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: Do you need to only change the colors once and only for the first time the buttom is clicked? Do you want all the color changes to change to the same new color?

Comment: I'd suggest giving the inputs a class or data-attribute that you can then use in a [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) query to get those elements, and then a for loop / `forEach`.

Comment: Thank you, I have already been answered)